# How to compare two list of tuples with respect to index of position

Tags: python

I have the following data:

```
[('abc', 'bac'), ('cab', 'def')]
```

comparing `('abc', 'bac')`, we can see that in the first string `abc`, the index of `a` and `b` is different with respect to second string `bac` which is `b` and `a`, second index is `c` is same so in 2 is the output.

`('cab', 'def')`

comparing each element is different so out is 3.

Check each index of the position and take the difference

Expected Out

```
[2, 3]
```

Code

```
    list_ = [('abc', 'bac'), ('cab', 'def')]

for i,j in list_:
    x = (list(zip(i,j)))
    print (list(zip(i,j)))
```

Out

```
[('a', 'b'), ('b', 'a'), ('c', 'c')]
[('c', 'd'), ('a', 'e'), ('b', 'f')]
```

If add

```
count = 0
for i,j in x:
    if i != j:
        count += 1
print (count)
```

My Out is `3` , first diff `2` is not printing

Comment: Difference of what @Maws? Index is the position. What do you mean by index of position?

Comment: I think you're going to have to spell it out in a little more detail. It's not really clear what you're asking.

Comment: Do you want to compare index wise element of each tuple in your list? Please share what you have done so far

Comment: difference of each index

Comment: @Maws I don't understand what you mean. How do you arrive at the results above?

Comment: Kindly elaborate the question

Comment: What did you try? Please show your effort.

Comment: @stark9190, yes exactly

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You want to count the number of unequal letters in each string tuple, with "unequal" meaning *unequal with respect to position of the letter in the string*.

Since it's hard to do calculations with letters, I'd suggest to use their integer representation which you get from [ord](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord). For each `tuple` in the `list`, you can convert each letter in the string to `int`, take the difference and count the non-zero elements:

```py
l = [('abc', 'bac'), ('cab', 'def')]

result = []
for t in l:
    delta = map(lambda x, y: ord(x)-ord(y), *t)
    result.append(sum(1 for i in delta if i))

# result
# Out[7]: [2, 3]
```

As a 1-liner:

```py
result = [sum(1 for i in map(lambda x, y: ord(x)-ord(y), *t) if i) for t in l]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want something like:

Result is [2, 3] where:

`('abc', 'bac') = [1, 1, 0]` # values accumulated becomes end value "2".

and

`('cab', 'def') = [1, 1, 1]` # values accumulated becomes end value"3".

See my answer with inline comments below:

```py
dataset = [('abc', 'bac'), ('cab', 'def')]

end_result = []

for item in dataset:                    # use of word dataset prevents confusion related
                                        # to lists (regardless of the use "_".)
    print (item)
    x = (list(zip(item[0], item[1])))

    local_result = []

    print (x)

    for i,j in x:
        if i == j:
            local_result.append(0)   # adding non value to equal "letters" in item.
        else:
            local_result.append(1)   # if not equal count "1".
    print (local_result)

    count_results = 0

    for value in local_result:       # check the outcome of the local result and summarize its
                                     # findings in an end_result list for each
                                     # item in the dataset.
        if value == 1:
            count_results += 1

    end_result.append(count_results)

    print ("End result: %s" % end_result)

print (end_result)          # prints the overal end result "2, 3"
```

Output:

> ````
> [('a', 'b'), ('b', 'a'), ('c', 'c')]
> [1, 1, 0]
> End result: [2]
> ('cab', 'def')
> [('c', 'd'), ('a', 'e'), ('b', 'f')]
> [1, 1, 1]
> End result: [2, 3]
> [2, 3]```
> ````